# Compact but pretty JSON output in python?

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

JSON is written either with `indent=None` (default) as a single line (unreadable to a human eye) or with `ident=N` with a newline after each comma.

What I would like to see is a more compact but still pretty output, similar to what Common Lisp pretty-printing does.
E.g., instead of

```
 {
  "cleanup":{
   "cpu":6936.780000000001,
   "wall":7822.319401979446
  },
  "finished":"2017-08-14 18:36:23",
  "init":{
   "cpu":1365.73,
   "wall":1380.7802910804749
  },
  "job":"timings",
  "run":{
   "cpu":953.6700000000001,
   "wall":8350.496850013733
  },
  "started":"2017-08-14 13:28:06"
 }
```

I would like to see

```
 {
  "cleanup":{"cpu":6936.780000000001,"wall":7822.319401979446},
  "finished":"2017-08-14 18:36:23",
  "init":{"cpu":1365.73,"wall":1380.7802910804749},
  "job":"timings",
  "run":{"cpu":953.6700000000001,"wall":8350.496850013733},
  "started":"2017-08-14 13:28:06"
 }
```

similar to what [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) produces.

Comment: `compact=True` might get you half-way there...

Comment: English description: "if an object/array contains no objects/arrays as children, format it as a single line; else format it as multiple indented lines"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: the standard [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module does not support `compact=True`.

Comment: @o11c: this is a good start, although, if there are too many components, _some_ newlines+indent can be inserted.

Comment: @sds sorry, that was for `pprint`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I use python2

Comment: Modify the two `if _indent is None` lines  in `_make_iterencode` in the `json.encoder` module, then replace `JSONEncoder.iterencode` in a subclass. Lots of copypasta though :(

Answer (score 3):

This won't get it quite as tight as you want, but it is the format I find most satisfying.  You can test it online at https://beautifier.io/

```
pip install jsbeautifier
```

To use:

```
import jsbeautifier
print( jsbeautifier.beautify(json.dumps(data)) )
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify for help with formatting options and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible at this time, but when [RFE: more compact pretty printing](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/1337) is implemented, this question will be answered by using [python-rapidjson](https://github.com/python-rapidjson/python-rapidjson).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a tool that already does this, but it isn't hard to make one:

```
def compact(d):
    def tight(obj):
        return dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'))
    print('{')
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        comma = ',' if i < len(d) else ''
        print(f' {tight(k)}:{tight(v)}{comma}')
    print('}')
```

For your example, this emits:

```
>>> compact(d)
{
 "cleanup":{"cpu":6936.780000000001,"wall":7822.319401979446},
 "finished":"2017-08-14 18:36:23",
 "init":{"cpu":1365.73,"wall":1380.7802910804749},
 "job":"timings",
 "run":{"cpu":953.6700000000001,"wall":8350.496850013733},
 "started":"2017-08-14 13:28:06",
}
```

Comment: This does not handle deeper nesting and more complex structures.

Comment: @sds Adding a little recursion isn't hard to do.  The purpose of an answer is to point the way. It is not the job of respondent to write a production tool that meets all desires for all possible users.  In this case, it produces exactly what the OP asked for and it easy to understand.

Comment: What will be the library for `dumps`?