# How do I debug an error in `ast.literal_eval`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, abstract-syntax-tree

I wrote my data to a file using [`pprint.PrettyPrinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) and I am trying to read it using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).
This has been working for me for quite some time, and I am reasonably satisfied with the text representation produced.

However, today I got this error on deserialization:

```
  File "/...mypath.../store.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    reader=(lambda fd: ast.literal_eval(fd.read())),
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 60, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

#### How do I fix this specific file?

The file in question is 17k lines/700kb.
I loaded it into Emacs -- the parens are balanced. 
There are no non-ASCII characters in the file.
I can "divide and conquer" (split the file in half and try to real each half) - but this is rather tedious.
Is there anything better?

I modified `ast.literal_eval:_convert` to print the offending node - it turned out to be `<_ast.UnaryOp object at 0x110696510>`. Not very helpful.

#### How do I ensure that this does not happen in the future?

I hope `JSON` is not the answer. ;-)

I am not using `JSON` because

1. [JSON cannot handle non-string dict keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28055565/850781)
2. [JSON inserts either too many newlines or none at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45681702/850781)

Comment: If you can get a reference to the offending node, print out its `lineno` and `col_offset` attributes - that should tell you the exact location of the problem.

Comment: Could you show a (simplified) example of your file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The question is about trying to find where in the file the problem is. A simplified version of the file probably wouldn’t have the error at all.

Comment: Quick guess, might or might not pay off: search for `set` in your file. `ast.literal_eval` can't handle empty sets.

Comment: @jasonharper: yep, that did it. Thanks! The problem was that I triggered a known [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue15245): `ast.literal_eval(str(float("inf")))` (please convert your comment to an answer, I will gladly accept it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Quick and Dirty

#### Apply this patch:

```
--- /...../2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py.old 2018-03-25 12:17:11.000000000 -0400
+++ /...../2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py 2018-03-25 12:17:18.000000000 -0400
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ def literal_eval(node_or_string):
                 return left + right
             else:
                 return left - right
-        raise ValueError('malformed string')
+        raise ValueError('malformed string', node.lineno, node.col_offset)
     return _convert(node_or_string)
```

#### Reload `ast`:

```
>>> reload(ast)
```

#### Retry loading the offending file

Get

```
ValueError: ('malformed string', 21161, 10)
```

then line 21161, column 10 is where the error is.

[Bug report submitted](https://bugs.python.org/issue42561).

## Sophisticated

Wrap the code in [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), catch the error and use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html)/[`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/traceback.html) to access the `node` in question:

```
try:
    ast.literal_eval(...)
except ValueError as ex:
    _exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print("ERROR: %r" % (exc_value))
    # traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback)
    last_tb = exc_traceback
    while last_tb.tb_next:
        last_tb = last_tb.tb_next
    print("Error location: line=%d, col=%d" % (
        last_tb.tb_frame.f_locals["node"].lineno,
        last_tb.tb_frame.f_locals["node"].col_offset))
```

prints

```
ERROR: ValueError('malformed string')
Error location: line=21933, col=15
```

Comment: Great answer. This should really be the default behaviour of the module