# How do I read python2 long integer syntax into python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an old file written using python2, which contains things like `148191387849281587952L`.
When I try to read it (using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)) in python3, I, naturally, get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Is there anything I could do to read the file into python3?

PS. The only solutions I see at this time require modifying the file:

1. Convert to JSON: read the file into python2, write it using json, then read into python3 using json.
2. Remove the offending `L` using `sed -i 's/([0-9]+)L/\1/g'`.
3. Convert the file using [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/2to3.html) (suggested by @user3080953).

Is there anything better?

Comment: I like the idea of using a version-agnostic serialization approach, such as JSON, but I think your solution #1 seems a little roundabout. It sounds like your idea is "write the file using python2, then read it in python2, then write it with json, then read it in python 3 using json", it seems like it would be easier to modify your original program so it writes json in the first place. That'll save you two steps.

Comment: You shouldn't have a file with python object representations in first place - they are not a reliable storage method!

Comment: @Kevin: I have a bunch of old files written by python2, and I need to read them into python3

Comment: @nosklo: [JSON takes up too much screen real estate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45681702/850781) ;-) but you are right, JSON is, alas, the way to go...

Comment: @sds time to put those ultrawide monitors to use

Comment: @nosklo: the problem is that JSON is either "horizontal" (`ident=None`, no structure, virtually unreadable) or "vertical" (`ident!=None`, one object per line, many many many lines per record).

Comment: @sds I was joking - json is not for humans to read. Make a gui program to read your data and display to the user as a nicely formatted report, with graphics.

Comment: Would running 2to3 on the file fix it? It seems like a simple case that should be handled by that

Comment: @user3080953: yes! thanks! this is a 3rd solution I want to avoid :-)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to avoid solutions instead of fixing the problem. Here's another one: read it in Python2 and write new files in JSON or some other common format.

Comment: @Elazar: that's the solution #1 on my list. My question is: can I modify Python3 syntax to read `L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your clarification, there is a simple answer:

No, you cannot modify `ast.leteral_eval()` or the python interpreter to be "backwards compatible" with the `L` syntax.

Comment: (Nor would I consider it to be a good idea, changing the interpreter in order to read  external data)